# When adding a Bluetooth device, all detected devices show up as "Unknown Device." How do I fix this?

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth

In Windows 10, I attempt to add a new Bluetooth device by 'adding Bluetooth or other device' and choosing Bluetoooth from the 'Add a device' window.

My device is a Bluetooth mouse that has been added to other laptops, where it has enumerated properly. The mouse is turned on and is discoverable.

The list of devices I could add populates, but all devices are titled "Unknown device."

How can I get Windows to list devices by name?[image: Windows 10 Add a device dialog]

Comment: What are the devices you are trying to add?  Are they Windows 10 Compatible?

Comment: A mouse. Yes, it's compatible. It works on other Windows 10 laptops. Additionally, all devices are shown as "Unknown device."

Comment: Try running DISM and SFC.  Open an admin command prompt, run dism.exe /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth and follow this by SFC /SCANNOW .  When done, restart and test

Comment: Ugh. Windows. If it's not working, throw some general commands at it and cross your fingers. Run a registry cleaner to speed up your system. Run a second registry cleaner to speed it up again. This kind of answer supports the idea computers are "glitching."

Comment: The commands above are the main command to fix Windows 10 (not just throwing commands around). If that did not work, run a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation Link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: Could the drivers be the problem? Open Device Manager and try updating (installing?) the drivers.

Comment: Hi, good point. I did already uninstall the Bluetooth device, including removing the driver files. I then got the latest driver from Intel for my hardware and installed it. There was no change.